# How can i make 2nd HDD in Macbook stay spun down (OS X El Capitan)?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, sleep, optical-drive, osx-el-capitan

I installed a 2nd HDD in my 2012 macbook pro 13" about a year ago, and i used this script that i found online to put my drive to sleep and wake it up:

```
tell application "Finder"   
if not (exists the disk "HDD") then   
do shell script "diskutil mountDisk 'disk1'"      
else   
do shell script "diskutil eject 'disk1'"      
end if   
end tell
```

That worked out just fine until I upgraded to El Capitan. Now I can still put my disk to sleep, but after 10-20 seconds it spins back up. I have tried all tips from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/251969/disable-or-sleep-secondary-hard-drive-in-macbook) thread, by setting idle time to one minute, preventing spotlight from indexing and searching the disk and now I am completely out of ideas. Do anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've noticed some changes in functionality in my Applescripts as well in this OS version. Have you tried debugging in the script editor?

Comment: I am quite new to this whole programming world, and have never written a word in applescript before this, so I don't really know how to debug. I read some about script debugger, but that is way to expensive for one task. Can I do it from within apple script?

Comment: Yes you can. Just launch Script from the Applications/Utilities and use the `debug.print` feature in AS to print variables to the debug window while your code is running. I also use dialogue boxes to show variable states since they require interaction from me and pause the processing until I hit `OK`. The downside is you don't have a trail like you do with the debug window.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me using script editor:

`tell application "Finder"
    if (exists disk "Momentus_XT_750GB") then
        try
            tell application "ejectHDD" to activate
        end try
    else
        try
            do shell script "diskutil mountDisk 'disk0'"
        end try
    end if
end tell`

I used automator to make the ejectHDD app following this [link](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/automatically-eject-disks-at-boot-in-mac-os-x-with-automator/)